# What does “It’s presumptions of you” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Boys at school invited a new girl that just came to this school to go to a Halloween party with them and the girl said:

> It’s presumptions of you

What does it mean?

Comment: The word **Halloween** starts with a capital H. You may see it sometimes in older texts as **Hallowe'en**.

Comment: This is not an accurate description or transcription of what happened. And you should have said where you heard this exactly. (Me, I know my Stranger Things, at least.)

Answer (score 3):

It's a malapropism.  Either by the author or put in the character's mouth by the author.

Normally, one would expect

> It’s presumptuous of you

which in context would have to mean that they are presuming that their brief acquaintance means she will go to a party with them.  She would have to know a boy better before accepting such an invitation.

If it's the only malapropism, I would assume it's an error, but if she often uses them (and they appear in no other context), it would indicate that she uses big words without quite understanding them.

Comment: The malapropism was introduced by OP, not the [original scene](http://strangerfansblog.com/2019/09/25/funniest-scenes/).